# Deploying a project using Visual C++ and the QT plugin for VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, visual-c++, deployment

I've created an application in C++ using Visual Studio 2010 as my IDE. I used the QT plugin for Visual Studio to create my GUI and also use the VTK and OpenCV libraries. What is the simplest way to deploy my application? I've already tried pasting the DLLs for QT, VTK, and OpenCV in my exe folder and, although this runs on other computers, the formatting and program speed are wildly different than what I get on my computer.

Comment: What formatting changes are you seeing?  Are images not loading?  Also vtk and opencv are both pretty heavy processing libraries.  If the computer is using a lightweight integrated graphics card, vs a high end dedicated graphics card, you will see a big difference in performance.  I've even seen laptops that perform differently with graphics and animations when plugged in and when they are not plugged in.  Manufacturers try to save power and battery life by cutting back the abilities of the graphics card.  BTW using threading properly can make a big difference.

Comment: I'm rendering an image, computing the silhouette (both through VTK), and running a canny edge detection through openCV to extract the contours. Both the rendering process and the edge detection process slow to about 1/20th of what I get  on my computer. Interestingly the computers I've been testing all have much better GPUs/CPUs than my computer.

Comment: With regard to formatting, fonts appear bigger, buttons are not aligned properly. I suppose this is an issue with my deployment of QT. I'll try AntonD's method and report back with the results.

Answer (score 2):

So, you have 2 possible ways:

1. Static deploy.
2. Shared deploy.

Description both of them you can find [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html)
As i see the shared deploy is too difficult for you, because you're using heavy libraries.
So, my advice is that satic deploy will be better :)

Please, try to build Qt, libs, and your app static, and we'll see how it will works.